# If $h$ can be extended to a continuous map $\Bbb R^n \to Y$, then show that $h_\ast:\pi_1(A,a_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and let $Y$ be a topological space. Let $a_0 \in A$ and $y_0 \in Y$. Suppose that $h : A \to Y$ is a continuous map with $h(a_0)=y_0.$ If $h$ can be extended to a continuous map $\Bbb R^n \to Y$, then show that $h_\ast:\pi_1(A,a_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Suppose that $h$ extends to a map $f :\Bbb R^n \to Y$, then $f \mid_A = h$ i.e. if $\iota:A \to \Bbb R^n$ is the inclusion map we have  that $f \circ \iota = h$.

Now applying the functor $\pi_1$ I think I get that $f_\ast : \pi_1(\Bbb R^n) \to \pi_1(Y)$ must be the trivial homomorphism as $\Bbb R^n$ is contractible and $\pi_1(\Bbb R^n) =0$.

How can I tie this with the map $h_\ast:\pi_1(A,a_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$? Is it due to the composition $h_\ast = f_\ast \circ \iota_\ast$ that $h_\ast$ must also be trivial?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: Thank you Paul! @PaulFrost